# wso2 identity server startup error v 5.11.0 windows 10

Tags: wso2, startup

```
TID: [-1234] [] [2022-02-26 15:41:04,837] []  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.CarbonCoreActivator} - Starting WSO2 Carbon...
TID: [-1] [] [2022-02-26 15:41:04,837]    []  INFO {org.ops4j.pax.logging.spi.support.EventAdminConfigurationNotifier} - Sending Event Admin nofification (configuration successful) to org/ops4j/pax/logging/Configuration
TID: [-1234] [] [2022-02-26 15:41:04,843] []  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.CarbonCoreActivator} - Operating System : Windows 10 10.0, amd64
TID: [-1234] [] [2022-02-26 15:41:04,843] []  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.CarbonCoreActivator} - Java Home        : C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_321\jre
TID: [-1234] [] [2022-02-26 15:41:04,843] []  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.CarbonCoreActivator} - Java Version     : 1.8.0_321
TID: [-1234] [] [2022-02-26 15:41:04,844] []  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.CarbonCoreActivator} - Java VM          : Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 25.321-b07,Oracle Corporation
TID: [-1234] [] [2022-02-26 15:41:04,844] []  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.CarbonCoreActivator} - Carbon Home      : \PROGRA~1\WSO2\IDENTI~1\5.11.0
TID: [-1234] [] [2022-02-26 15:41:04,844] []  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.CarbonCoreActivator} - Java Temp Dir    : \PROGRA~1\WSO2\IDENTI~1\5.11.0\tmp
TID: [-1234] [] [2022-02-26 15:41:04,844] []  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.CarbonCoreActivator} - User             : Sampath Kumar, en-IN, Asia/Calcutta
TID: [-1] [] [2022-02-26 15:41:05,070]    []  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.event.output.adapter.kafka.internal.ds.KafkaEventAdapterServiceDS} - Successfully deployed the Kafka output event adaptor service
TID: [-1] [] [2022-02-26 15:41:05,451]    []  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth.uma.grant.internal.UMA2GrantServiceComponent} - Policy evaluator registered successfully: DefaultPolicyEvaluator
TID: [-1] [] [2022-02-26 15:41:05,452]    []  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth.uma.grant.internal.UMA2GrantServiceComponent} - UMA Grant component activated successfully.
TID: [-1234] [] [2022-02-26 15:41:05,801] []  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.ldap.server.configuration.LDAPConfigurationBuilder} - KDC server is disabled.
TID: [-1234] [] [2022-02-26 15:41:08,518] []  INFO {org.apache.directory.server.KERBEROS_LOG} - KeyDerivation Interceptor initialized
TID: [-1] [] [2022-02-26 15:41:09,571] []  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.mex.internal.Office365SupportMexComponent} - Office365Support MexServiceComponent bundle activated successfully..
TID: [-1] [] [2022-02-26 15:41:09,580] []  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.mex2.internal.DynamicCRMCustomMexComponent} - DynamicCRMSupport MexServiceComponent bundle activated successfully.
TID: [-1] [] [2022-02-26 15:41:10,624] [] ERROR {org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase} - A child container failed during start java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot@9f03abb]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:916)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:841)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1384)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1374)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
    at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:134)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:909)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:262)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.service.ExtendedStandardService.startInternal(ExtendedStandardService.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:930)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.internal.CarbonTomcat.start(CarbonTomcat.java:113)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.internal.ServerManager$1.run(ServerManager.java:167)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot@9f03abb]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.handleSubClassException(LifecycleBase.java:440)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:198)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.resourcesStart(StandardContext.java:4805)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:4940)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1384)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1374)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
    at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:134)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:909)
    ... 17 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The main resource set specified [C:\Program Files\WSO2\Identity Server\5.11.0\lib\tomcat\PROGRA~1\WSO2\IDENTI~1\5.11.0\repository\deployment\server\webapps\PROGRA~1\WSO2\IDENTI~1\5.11.0\repository\conf\tomcat\carbon] is not valid
    at org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot.createMainResourceSet(StandardRoot.java:752)
    at org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot.startInternal(StandardRoot.java:709)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    ... 26 more

TID: [-1] [] [2022-02-26 15:41:10,645] [] ERROR {org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase} - A child container failed during start java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:916)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:262)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.service.ExtendedStandardService.startInternal(ExtendedStandardService.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:930)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.internal.CarbonTomcat.start(CarbonTomcat.java:113)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.internal.ServerManager$1.run(ServerManager.java:167)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:928)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:841)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1384)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1374)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
    at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:134)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:909)
    ... 9 more
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot@9f03abb]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:916)
    ... 17 more
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot@9f03abb]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.handleSubClassException(LifecycleBase.java:440)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:198)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.resourcesStart(StandardContext.java:4805)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:4940)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1384)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1374)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
    at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:134)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:909)
    ... 17 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The main resource set specified [C:\Program Files\WSO2\Identity Server\5.11.0\lib\tomcat\PROGRA~1\WSO2\IDENTI~1\5.11.0\repository\deployment\server\webapps\PROGRA~1\WSO2\IDENTI~1\5.11.0\repository\conf\tomcat\carbon] is not valid
    at org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot.createMainResourceSet(StandardRoot.java:752)
    at org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot.startInternal(StandardRoot.java:709)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    ... 26 more

TID: [-1] [] [2022-02-26 15:41:10,656] [] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.internal.ServerManager} - tomcat life-cycle exception org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:928)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:262)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.service.ExtendedStandardService.startInternal(ExtendedStandardService.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:930)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.internal.CarbonTomcat.start(CarbonTomcat.java:113)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.internal.ServerManager$1.run(ServerManager.java:167)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:916)
    ... 9 more
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:928)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:841)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1384)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1374)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
    at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:134)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:909)
    ... 9 more
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot@9f03abb]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:916)
    ... 17 more
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot@9f03abb]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.handleSubClassException(LifecycleBase.java:440)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:198)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.resourcesStart(StandardContext.java:4805)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:4940)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1384)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1374)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
    at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:134)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:909)
    ... 17 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The main resource set specified [C:\Program Files\WSO2\Identity Server\5.11.0\lib\tomcat\PROGRA~1\WSO2\IDENTI~1\5.11.0\repository\deployment\server\webapps\PROGRA~1\WSO2\IDENTI~1\5.11.0\repository\conf\tomcat\carbon] is not valid
    at org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot.createMainResourceSet(StandardRoot.java:752)
    at org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot.startInternal(StandardRoot.java:709)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    ... 26 more

TID: [-1234] [] [2022-02-26 15:41:11,021] []  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.UniqueIDReadWriteLDAPUserStoreManager} - LDAP connection created successfully in read-write mode
TID: [-1234] [] [2022-02-26 15:41:11,090] []  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.consent.mgt.core.internal.ConsentManagerComponent} - ConsentManagerComponent is activated.
TID: [-1234] [] [2022-02-26 15:41:11,477] []  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.EmbeddedRegistryService} - Configured Registry in 47ms
TID: [-1234] [] [2022-02-26 15:41:11,500] []  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.EmbeddedRegistryService} - Connected to mount at configregistry in 4ms
TID: [-1234] [] [2022-02-26 15:41:11,501] []  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.EmbeddedRegistryService} - Connected to mount at govregistry in 5ms
TID: [-1234] [] [2022-02-26 15:41:11,546] []  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.EmbeddedRegistryService} - Connected to mount at configregistry in 0ms
TID: [-1234] [] [2022-02-26 15:41:11,552] []  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.EmbeddedRegistryService} - Connected to mount at govregistry in 1ms
TID: [-1234] [] [2022-02-26 15:41:11,560] []  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.internal.RegistryCoreServiceComponent} - Registry Mode    : READ-WRITE
TID: [-1234] [] [2022-02-26 15:41:11,616] []  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.metrics.impl.util.JmxReporterBuilder} - Creating JMX reporter for Metrics with domain 'org.wso2.carbon.metrics'
TID: [-1234] [] [2022-02-26 15:41:11,621] []  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.metrics.impl.reporter.AbstractReporter} - Started JMX reporter for Metrics
TID: [-1234] [] [2022-02-26 15:41:13,086] []  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.registry.indexing.solr.SolrClient} - Default Embedded Solr Server Initialized
TID: [-1234] [] [2022-02-26 15:41:13,214] []  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.internal.UserStoreMgtDSComponent} - Carbon UserStoreMgtDSComponent activated successfully.
```

Answer (score 0):

As the error indicates, there is some problem with tomcat configuration.

1. Cross check if you have made any changes to your <IS_HOME>\repository\conf\deployment.toml wrt tomcat
2. try starting the wso2 IS after installing before making any change

you are getting this error, after any particular configuration? provide details to help.